# windows 8.1 opening random websites, apps

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, wake-up

i just got a new asus q551l.  it has windows 8.1 on it.  every time i put it to sleep it and i go back to check on it, it is already awake with some random websites open, or random apps.  i do not understand why this keeps happening.  yesterday after i came to discover its premature awakening, i found bing's default-search virus? on my desktop with several webpages open.  there were 2 of those icons.  i recycle binned them and ran my antivirus avast, which said everything was ok.  but these random websites and apps keep preventing my computer from staying asleep.  i already did the procedure of disabling both "allow wake timers."  so far the apps that have awaken my computer are "food and drink" and skype.  the websites are random as well. obscure youtube videos.  right now there was my gmail page that i clearly x'd out of before i put the computer to sleep.  in addition to my gmail page, there are 5 octopus publishing group pages open.  what are all these obscure websites??  do i have a virus??  this is a brand new laptop, and all i've downloaded is vlc from a safe source, and my mmorpg game from the game makers' website, and also avast.  that is it.  please help!!

Comment: There's a myriad of ways you could have accidentally allowed some sort of malware to access your PC. First suggestion would be to try to "system restore" to the last restore point created before this started, then as first order of business doublecheck your antivirus installation and run Windows Update until it says there are no updates available any more.

Comment: Could be a case of browser hijacking.. try doing reset as a first step (For Firefox - Help - Troubleshooting Information - Reset Firefox. For Chrome - Settings - Advanced Settings - Reset Settings). If after resetting browser it is still re-appearing, there may be some resident program that re-instating the browser hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

Clean install your machine, fully update it ASAP and before browsing any websites, switch to Chrome or Firefox and make sure you do not go to bad websites and click on links you do not trust. Have a decent and up to date antivirus running at all times.

Just in case: never install pirated software, or even go to such websites.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some malicious software installed or running in your computer.

Download & Install: http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx 
Making click in: "Skip details and take me to the download" 
Run Full Scan

Download & install: http://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/var4-nodl/ 
Run Full Scan 
Delete all you find and restart computer.

Just do the maintenance of your computer downloading and running CCleaner 
https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/standard

Check the Initial files and see if you find any ".exe" suspicious.

and That's it